# Make Open Office Table of Contents Link to Page, not Heading

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I have a Table of Contents in my (Apache) Open Office document. It works fine, except that the hyperlinks go to the headings used to generate the Table of Contents, not the top of the page they reside on. My chapter title pages have text above the actual chapter title, which is the text the Table of Contents header is applied to, and following these links (which also are being used to make the PDF index) cuts off the text above the title. As such, I am looking for a way to override the destination of the Table of Contents links, so that they point to the heading's page top, rather than the heading itself.

I should also clarify I wish to do this without manually editing the Table of Contents, as that would largely defeat the purpose of using one.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do this without using a Macro or manipulating the ODT file content. You may extend the space at the top of a heading and put some content there, using a frame. But this works only inside OOo; a PDF Viewer will usually jump to the heading itself, ignoring the additional top spacing.

Comment: @tohuwawohu do you know of any word processing programs that CAN do that? I know from professional PDFs (like ebooks) that it can be done, and frankly, Open Office has annoyed me in enough ways to be willing to switch. This wasn't initially important to me, but I decided to publish my story in PDF format, so I want it to be as professional as possible.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know such software. But - if your aim is to create a ebook (so the link-to-page doesn't have to work inside OOo necessarily), you could try to directly import your odt file into a tool like [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). Maybe it will work out of the box.